# Why are spaces between imgs if margin and padding are 0?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, cross-browser

Why are spaces between imgs if margin and padding are 0?  Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/4gk49/2/

Why are those spaces between images if `li`s and `img`s have margin and padding set to zero?

Why is this happening?

The desired behavior would be to have all the images together always in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the actual whitespace between tags... Try:

```
<li><img src="/Content/img/slider/1.jpg" alt="1" /></li><li><img
 src="/Content/img/slider/2.jpg" alt="2" /></li><li><img
 src="/Content/img/slider/3.jpg" alt="3" /></li><li><img
 src="/Content/img/slider/4.jpg" alt="4" /></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Images are `inline` by default. Try setting `display: block`.

Comment: Or `display: inline-block`, depending on whether you want them stacked next to each other (`inline-block`) or on top of each other (`block`).

Comment: I've tried, but don`t work http://jsfiddle.net/4gk49/4/ , the same with inline-block, Kyle's answer worked! thanks to all!